# Getting user`s UUID from django server

Tags: python, django, device, uuid, user-identification

I have a django server with an admin panel. 
Different users make changes there and this is saved via auditlog in the database and displayed in the "history". 
But there are situations when a user enters under the account of another user and makes changes on his behalf. 
In order to identify from which device this or that change was made, it was a nice decision to also record data about the IP of the user from whom the change was made, and his unique device number. 
By overloading several methods in the "AuditlogMiddleware" class, I got the desired result via "uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode())".
(Tested locally, because the prod server is heavily loaded and there is no way to do test committees)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import threading
import time

from auditlog.middleware import AuditlogMiddleware


threadlocal = threading.local()


class ExtendedAuditlogMiddleware(AuditlogMiddleware):

    def process_request(self, request):
        threadlocal.auditlog = {
            'signal_duid': (self.__class__, time.time()),
            'remote_addr': request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'),
        }
        super(ExtendedAuditlogMiddleware, self).process_request(request)

        **#changes here
        import uuid
        threadlocal.auditlog['additional_data'] = str(uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode()))+" | "+request.META["USERNAME"]**

    # @staticmethod
    def set_actor(self, user, sender, instance, signal_duid, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedAuditlogMiddleware, self).set_actor(user, sender, instance, signal_duid, **kwargs)
        
        **#changes here
        instance.additional_data = threadlocal.auditlog['additional_data']**
```

But the problem is that I think I get the UUID not of the user, but of the server, because there is no access to the user, i guess. I couldn't find the information, and I couldn't come up with my own solution either.
Question - is it even possible to get information from the server about django admin users' devices??
If not, what can i use instead of UUID to identify which device was used while making changes in django admin panel??
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to use javascript in side of your template to send this info thrugh

Comment: Could you please give more information how to get access for user`s device via js in template??

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).